# Multiple Swipers move at the same time with onTouchStart

Tags: angular, swiper.js

I have a page (on angular 4) with multiple swipers, and I want to when touch a Swiper (any of them), all swipers move at the same time. Actually, when I touch a swiper for move, the swiper works, but others Swipers don't move.

**My HTML**

```
<swiper [config]="config">
    <section class="swiper-wrapper">
      <article *ngFor="let article of articles" class="swiper-slide">
        <!--Code-->
      </article>
    </section>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </swiper>

  <!--Code-->

  <section *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <swiper [config]="config">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <span class="swiper-slide" *ngFor="let col of row.columns">
          <p *ngFor="let detail of col">{{detail}}</p>
        </span>
      </div>
    </swiper>
  </section>
```

**My config into ngOnInit**

```
this.config = {
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  centeredSlides: true,
  pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
  paginationClickable: true
};
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Add the below mentioned script and link tag in index.html:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.1/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.1/css/swiper.min.css">
```

2.Add the below given function in '.ts' file of respective swiper slider component.

```
declare var Swiper: any;

ngOnInit() {
   var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
     direction: 'horizontal',
     loop: true,
     effect: 'slide',
     observer: true, 
      observeParents: true
    });
}
```